# Show rank of matrix is $m$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, proof-writing

> Let $X$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and let $Y$ be an $n \times m$ matrix such that $XY = I_m$. Prove that $\text{rank} Y = m$

Not even sure where to start, would appreciate some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
m = \operatorname{rank}(XY) \leq \operatorname{rank}(Y) \leq m
$$
I'll leave it to you to justify the inequalities.

Comment: Since $Y$ is a right inverse of $X$, we must have $m \le n$, thus $\text{rank} Y \le \min(m, n) = m$, we have that $\text{rank} XY = \text{rank } I_m = m$, we must have $\text{rank } XY \le \text{rank } Y$, since $m \le n$, we can have $\ge m$ leading ones in $\text{RREF} Y$, thus $m = \text{rank } XY \le \text{rank } Y \le m$, it follows $m \le \text{rank } Y \le m \implies \text{rank } Y = m$.

Comment: We always have $\text{rank} Y \le \min(m, n)  \leq m$, so that bit about the right inverse wasn't necessary.  It's still not clear to me how you deduced that $\operatorname{rank} (XY)≤\operatorname{rank}(Y)$.  How does the number of leading $1$s in $RREF(Y)$ compare to the number of leading $1$s in $RREF(XY)$?

Comment: I am having trouble deducing $\text{rank} XY \le \text{rank} Y$. How can I do this?

Comment: Probably, the inequality $\operatorname{rank}(X,Y) \leq \min\{\operatorname{rank}(X),\operatorname{rank}(Y)\}$ is given somewhere in your notes.  That being said, we could also prove it ourselves.  The other answer gives you one proof in terms of linear mappings.  Another idea is to note that if $y_1,\dots,y_r$ is a basis for the column space of $Y$, then $Xy_1,\dots,Xy_r$ is a *spanning set* (possibly linearly dependent) of the column space of $XY$.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/935253/81360)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider matrices as linear mappings (choosing a basis). Then $I_m$ corresponds to identity of an $m$-dimensional space, which is specially an isomorphism, hence epimorphism (i.e. rank of the image is $m$).

Similarly, you can consider $X$ and $Y$ to be linear mappings. In general, the rank of the image cannot be greater than the rank of the range, so $m = rank (I_m) = rank (XY) \leq rank (Y) \leq m$.